# Crystal Report Formula to print difference of a column field according to group id

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am making a report using Crystal report. My column data(Amount) is grouped according to id(1 and 2). I want to print difference of total sum of amount according to id(1 and 2).

For eg:- 
 In group id 1, amount field are:-
 100
 200
 300

And in group id 2 amount fileds are:-
 50
 150
 250

My output in crystal report should be: 1-2
 i.e: (100+200+300) - (50+150+250)

Please help me. I have tried doing it through formula field in this way:-

```
local numbervar x=0;

if({Statement_of_Pay.Pay_Head_Type_Code}=1)
then
x:= x + {Statement_of_Pay.Amount}
else if({Statement_of_Pay.Pay_Head_Type_Code}=2)
then
x:= x - {Statement_of_Pay.Amount}
```

This is not working the way I want.
Kindly help me!

Comment: where do you need the output to be displayed? and what is the problem with the above formula?

Answer (score 0):

For summation you can use the `sum` option in crystal reports instead of writing a formula as you did.

Below solution works assuming `group ID 1,2` are the results of the same group not `2 groups`.

1. Take the sum of the column by going to `Right Click ---> Insert Summary` and insert summary to the level you required.
2. Create a formula `@Group1`

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   Shared NumberVar Storegroup1;
   if(GroupNumber=1)
    then
   Storegroup1:=sum({databasefield},{groupid});
   ```
3. Create a formula `@Group2`

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   Shared NumberVar Storegroup2;
   if(GroupNumber=2)
   then
   Storegroup1:=sum({databasefield},{groupid});
   ```

now take the difference in the section you require. Create a formula `@Display`

```
EvaluateAfter(@Group1);
EvaluateAfter(@Group2);

Shared NumberVar Storegroup1;
Shared NumberVar Storegroup2;

Storegroup1-Storegroup2;
```